# Is there any tool for migrating etl RPG processes to a modern ETL tool?

Tags: migration, etl, rpgle

I need a piece of advice. I've been working with ETL Tools such as DataStage, Kettle, etc. for the last few years. Now I'm working in a company without any ETL tool which has its ETL processes in legacy RPG (IBM i). They want to migrate to an ETL Tool, so I'm working on investigating which is the right tool. But the thing is that moving from RPG to an ETL tool would implicate to re-write all the ETL processes, because I can't find a tool that can do this job for us. Is there any a way or tool to do this? 
Is possible to run RPG from a job in an ETL tool?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can't decide if this question is off topic or not...

I can't "recommend a tool" since I'm unaware of any specific tools that would migrate RPG to an ETL tool.  Though there are (used to be?) tools that tried to migrate RPG code to another languages.

I will point out that RPG is far from the only supported language on the IBM i.

Java for instance is quite well supported, calling RPG programs from Java is easily accomplished.  Rather or not a Java based ETL tool provides some way to surface that functionality is another story.

Additionally, IBM has done a lot to support [opensource](https://bitbucket.org/ibmi/opensource/wiki/Home) on the IBM i.  Node.js, Python, Rudy, and PHP are all supported on the i.  AFAIK, there's a way to call RPG programs from all of them.